# Inserting Schedules based on a day(Monday,..) into MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I building an application that will require the admin to create bus schedules based on a DAYNAME(Monday,..) in a particular MONTH(September,..) and in a particular YEAR(2012). So for every Monday in September, 2o12 the bus schedules will be added. This will happen too if the bus has a Tuesday Schedule, Wednesday, etc.

So I want this to run iteratively too, so for all the month in 2012 or 2013, for every monday add a bus schedule

I have a single table with columns; dept_time,_dept_date,date_of_travel etc.
I think a stored procedure will be the best solution.

Please I need ideas on how to implement this.

Thank you.

Comment: This question needs to be flagged as "NOT A REA QUESTION" OR "Too localized" ... However I will prefer to guide rather than flagging it. "NOT A REAl QUESTION" means a question with does not make much sense or asking for a solution rather than asking some problem while making a solution. Too localized mean it would just help you and not useful for other community members or visitors. Suggestion: You should try to make some procedure or other solution then ask for any problem by showing(code) where you have problem. This question is about how to do? but seems others like what to do.

Comment: Thanks Sami, I was totally confused as how to go about this problem. @mvp's suggestions were really helpful. I can post the solution I came up with here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedure is not always a best solution (at least not in this case).

All you need is to create client side script or program (use Python, Perl, PHP, Java, etc) that will parse (and possibly validate) your business logic, and then insert records into your table according to that logic. This script should be the only entity that adds/updates records.

Finally, users will read (select) information from your table and use it as schedule.

Comment: Thanks mvp for the heads up. Much appreciated. My language of choice is PHP, any code sample? Thanks.

Comment: For PHP, PDO is suggested way to connect to database. Check out some PHP PDO tutorials, like this one http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php